# ts-node debug typescript function how to step into ts file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ts-node

I'm trying to debug some typescript file via ts-node to learn how Rxjs operator works, but when I press Step Into button, it jump to some js file,

While I hope I can reach the **original ts file**.

eg:

```
// src/index.ts
import { interval, map } from 'rxjs'

const interval$ = interval(1000)

interval$.pipe(map((x) => x + 1)) // add a break point here
```

When I press "Step Into" button, it jump to file **node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/index.js** and get this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "map", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return map_1.map; } }); var mapTo_1 = require("./internal/operators/mapTo");
```

Here is my lauch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch TS",
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "args": ["${file}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is **all** my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

and [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-leftpad-672srg) if needed.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @W.S. I hope to jump to the ts file.

Comment: If you want to learn more about rxjs operators, why don't you check the documentation? https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators or https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9wOu11uU6U&list=PL55RiY5tL51pHpagYcrN9ubNLVXF8rGVi&ab_channel=Academind

Comment: @W.S. is there any thing related to debug?

Comment: There probably isn't. Why would you debug an official npm package like rxjs which is already heavily tested on it's own and widely used.

Comment: I wanna know how it works under the hood but not check is there some bugs

Comment: FYI: this GitHub issue (although Nativescript) mentions `having a space in the workspace path is what causes the problem` https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-vscode-extension/issues/134

Comment: Under the hood: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/index.ts

Answer (score 1):

it's my fault that I didn't notice the field  `resolveSourceMapLocations` in `launch.json`, as it says "locations (folders and URLs) in which source maps can be used to resolve local files.", so I shouldn't add `"!**/node_modules/**"`

as a side note, don't delete the field `resolveSourceMapLocations` directly, if so it just behave like my question above described again.